# Creating animated blank popup that user can enter info into with html/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display a blank pop up box when a button is pressed. This display box would ideally let me set a header, then set the text and have fields Confirm (users can enter data) and Cancel. As per my approach, **this should be done by making a separate html file for this box and loading it when the button is clicked.**

However, I need the box to overlay the current page, and not open into new tab. I would like to add animations (which seems like can be done nicely with jquery).

I am finding different methods to create popups, but none are really like I am describing (because basically I want an animated popup that lets user enter information and click confirm or cancel to close it).

I am wondering if anyone can point me to methods do what I described or give me names of what I am describing to research how to do this.

The window.open() was kind of close, but it opens a completely new browser with specified dimensions, which I do not want.

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: This seems better suited for [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). For now, one thing I've used before is [bootstrap modals](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/). They should work for you.

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/ is worth a look. This guy has a decent blog entry on loading info in from a separate URL - http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/04/18/loading-a-page-into-a-dialog/

Comment: Thanks for the replies! The bootstrap modal looks a lot like what I need. Is the modal animatable? I'd love to it to slide down from the top then back up. I know the jquery dialog is very easy to animate as it has animation functions ready to go.